# QF-TEST:Button is not clickable in Chrome

Tags: button, components, qf-test

I have done recordings on a computer and a couple of tests that runs smoothly .Now i try to run on the same computer but the button is not clickable, it points to some where else on the webpage. The component value is the same .

[The button "anmelden" is not clickable it points to the filed on the nummber 2 displayed in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehMgB.png)

could anyone help me to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: a QFS Employee her.
There are meany possible reasons for the behavior that you describe. What you can do is to open a new empty testsuite and record the button again and then compare the old recording with the new one.

Also remember that you **must** use a **CustomWebResolver** in QF-Test in order to have a smooth and easy web-testing.